# match exception message in unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception

I'm unable to replicate the very end of this walkthrough 
[Walkthrough: Creating and Running Unit Tests for Managed Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182532%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Instead of my unit test passing, I get Debit_WhenAmountIsLessThanZero_ShouldThrowArgumentOutOfRange `failed. Expected:<Debit amount less than zero. Parameter name: amount Actual value was -100.>. Actual:<Debit amount less than zero.>.` I cannot figure out how to get just the message from the exception without getting the parameter information, which seems to be the expected behavior in the walkthrough.

Relevant part of my code from Debit in BankAccount.class:

```
  if (amount < 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("amount", amount, DebitAmountLessThanZeroMessage);
            }
```

Relevant part of my code from Debit_WhenAmountIsLessThanZero_ShouldThrowArgumentOutOfRange in BankAccountTests.cs:

```
        try
        {
            account.Debit(debitAmount);
        }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException e)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(e.Message, BankAccount.DebitAmountLessThanZeroMessage);
            return;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is rather brittle to rely on the exact text of an Exception message.

If the developer of the code you are calling changes the text, perhaps to provide more detail, your test of the exact message will fail.  That seems to be what has happened in this case.

If an Exception must convey additional useful information to the caller that can be processed in an automated manner, I would suggest a custom exception type that encodes that additional information.

To get this particular situation to pass the test, you can either edit the underlying code that throws the exception so that it throws the message text that your unit test expects, or modify the unit test to check for the message text that is actually being thrown.